# ERROR: ОШИБКА: отношение "city" уже существует

Tags: postgresql

Создаю через pgAdmin4 запрос, а он выдаёт ошибку "отношение "city" уже существует". Таблиц никаких нет, соответственно, связей тоже.

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_region integer NOT NULL,
  name varchar(250) NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO city (id, id_region, name) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Адыгейск'),
(2, 1, 'Майкоп'),
(3, 2, 'Горно-Алтайск'),
(4, 3, 'Алейск'),
(5, 3, 'Барнаул'),
(6, 3, 'Белокуриха'),
(7, 3, 'Бийск'),
(8, 3, 'Горняк'),
(9, 3, 'Заринск'),
(10, 3, 'Змеиногорск'),
(11, 3, 'Камень-на-Оби'),
(12, 3, 'Новоалтайск'),
(13, 3, 'Рубцовск'),
(14, 3, 'Славгород'),
(15, 3, 'Яровое'),
...
```

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, запросы почему-то подавались не в ту схему, наверное, что-то с правами в postgres.

Comment: Имейте привычку не работать без схем в Postgres.

Comment: Там есть схемы, не в этом дело

Comment: я имею виду CREATE TABLE {schemaname}.city и INSERT INTO {schemaname}.city и не будет таких проблем

Comment: Вот это уже хороший ответ , помогло бы в решении. Давайте я отмечу его, а не принимаются решения

Comment: Убрал строки, от них только скролл лишний и никакой пользы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имейте привычку работать со схемами

```
CREATE TABLE {schemaname}.city
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_region integer NOT NULL,
  name varchar(250) NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO {schemaname}.city (id, id_region, name) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Адыгейск'),
(2, 1, 'Майкоп'),
(3, 2, 'Горно-Алтайск'),
(4, 3, 'Алейск'),
(5, 3, 'Барнаул'),
(6, 3, 'Белокуриха'),
(7, 3, 'Бийск'),
(8, 3, 'Горняк'),
(9, 3, 'Заринск'),
(10, 3, 'Змеиногорск'),
(11, 3, 'Камень-на-Оби'),
(12, 3, 'Новоалтайск'),
(13, 3, 'Рубцовск'),
(14, 3, 'Славгород'),
(15, 3, 'Яровое');
```

и не будет таких проблем

Comment: @Kromster Да конечно без проблем